# Create an Ionic 3 app with transparent background

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3

I've made a simple blank ionic app and I would like to make it's background entirely transparent.

I've tried several methods to achieve the transparency of the app but the background always remains white.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean so you can see the phone home screen behind it?

Comment: @Shannon yes, because I will have just an text input and a button in the center of the screen.

Comment: I dont think this is possible with with Ionic directly. Ionic is contained in a webview which is like a stripped down browser. You may be able to access the native code via a Cordova Plugin and create a home screen "widget", this method will be different for both iOS and Android.